# SQLite, iCloud, and maybe Core Data—which to use for storing files and sharing them with all of the user's devices?

Tags: c++, ios, sqlite, core-data, icloud

I've been tasked with porting personal face recognition software to iOS and Mac OS X as well as helping keep the basic SDK and much of the software as cross-platform as possible.  One of the things one of my associates and I want to do is store data on the user's face in an SQL database (probably SQLite).  We would also like to allow users to put their data on iCloud so they don't have to train each of their devices separately to recognize them.  What's bugging me is how to do both these tasks, and I'm confronted with enough choices to feel overwhelmed.  (I am still new to some of the technologies involved.)

For implementing SQL, I could embed SQLite directly in my program and write code for it, or I could use Core Data and have it talk to SQLite for me.  (The database is not meant to be shared, so this is OK.  And SQL is not fun.)  However Core Data is anything but portable (not to mention not intended for a model encoded as C++ objects), while writing directly for SQL would mean we could reuse more code on other platforms.

Things get messier when factoring in iCloud, which has something like five or six possible ways of integrating it with a program.  The only method I have definitively ruled out so far is iCloud key-value storage.  (At the very least, there's a good chance a user would get into trouble with the 1 MB limit, and it is clearly not intended for anything as complex as I'm dealing with.)  Core Data can integrate with iCloud through UIManagedDocument or NSPersistentStore, but, again, that means less in the way of reusable code.  I can use SQLite together with UIDocument or NSDocument, but what I am trying to do seems to be not quite what these objects were intended for.  The files I am dealing with are essentially large preference files, not meant for end-users to interact with directly; UIDocument and NSDocument seem to be meant for user-viewable and -editable files.  And then there are iCloud Drive and CloudKit, which are still in beta.  (On the other hand, these two are due to be released fairly soon.  Considering that iOS users tend to upgrade to the latest version of the system software quickly, arguments about using either of these based on how many devices they will be able to run on should quickly become weak and obsolete.)

Can anyone recommend which way is best suited for my purposes?  Thanks in advance.

Aaron Solomon Adelman

Comment: use core data as a back end to store rather sqlite. and iCloud has built in support with core data

Comment: as you make port from other non-apple platforms, you probably want to sync data also with them, so you should look for cross platform syncing solutions - thus iCloud and CloudKit are not for you.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't want to try and share the SQLite file directly. That's extremely likely to corrupt the file, because SQLite wasn't built with that kind of use in mind.

However:

- You could use SQLite for local on-device storage only and use a separate API to send data back and forth. Apple's CloudKit would probably be a good choice if you can require iOS 8+. Numerous third party solutions exist (for example, [Parse](https://parse.com)). You'll have to write your own code to translate between SQLite and the network API. Your SQLite schema and your data files would be portable to other platforms, and **maybe** some of the code if you use SQLite's direct API instead of an Objective-C wrapper (and I highly recommend using either [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or [PLDatabase](https://opensource.plausible.coop/wiki/display/PLDB) if you use SQLite).
- Core Data does have built-in support for iCloud, which probably makes it a viable option. Your comment that *"...I could use Core Data and have it talk to SQLite for me."* suggests you might have somewhat misunderstood Core Data. Core Data is not a SQLite wrapper; it presents a completely different API, and uses its own schema. You can't really take a Core Data persistent store file and use it on other platforms unless you want to spend some time reverse-engineering the schema. Also, using Core Data with iCloud does not require the use of `UIManagedDocument`, though it does still require a lot of other Core Data-specific classes.
- If you want to be able to sync data across multiple devices *which are not all Apple devices* then you need a third party API. None of Apple's cloud APIs will be useful here. There are many providers that can help out with this. For local data storage, either SQLite or Core Data would work, but you should look at the third party services and see what storage option(s) they support, then try to work with them.

The best approach depends on your needs. If you expect to copy data files from an iOS app to other platforms, SQLite is good. You'll still have a lot of platform-specific code, the savings there are much less. If you don't plan to move data files around like that, Core Data is probably easier to deal with.